# sum of two square pyramidal numbers equal to a square pyramidal number (addendum)

Tags: combinatorics

A square pyramidal number is of the form SP(p) = p*(p+1)*(2p+1)/6 for any positive integer p.
There exist 3 integers p,q,r  such that SP(p) + SP(q) = SP(r)

For example:

p      q      r

24   69   70

42   45   55

50   145  147

124  225  237

126  212  226
...

Does there exist an infinite number of solutions with a general formula of recurrence?

Nota: the problem can be expressed in the following manner:
does there exist an infinite number of 3-uples (p,q,r) such that C(2p+2,3) + C(2q+2,3) = C(2r+2,3)?